# Restler with swagger-2.0

Tags: restler

Swagger 2.0 is AWESOME compared to the version Restler RC6 is using.  Is there any easy way to continue using the current RC6 branch but swap out the swagger-ui part for version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger 2 development is carried out in https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/features/swagger2.0 branch. Merge this with `v3` branch to get the desired output

Comment: Sorry could you give a little more detail please?  My Restler was installed via composer, so I don't actually have a git directory here that I can merge with.